# Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I am trying to inject one class (a simple PHP class) into another (an `ORM\Entity` annotated class), and getting an error, but I cannot discover the source. Looking at the code I feel like I am doing everything correctly, yet I cannot solve this error.

Here is the relevant code:

First, the class `ORM\Entity` where I want to inject the `ErrorConstants` class:

```
use Base\Model\Constants\ErrorConstants;

/**
* @ORM\Entity ...
*/
class CwPackagePeriod extends AbstractRestEntity
   public $errors;

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();

      $this->errors = new ErrorConstants();
   }
}
```

The `ErrorConstants` class is a simple class that contains a list of error constants:

```
class ErrorConstants
{
    public const ERR_MISSING = 'Record could not be found.';
}
```

The error occurs when I try to throw an exception in the `CwPackagePeriod` class if an integer value is out of bounds on a setter:

```
throw new InvalidOrMissingParameterException(
   sprintf($this->errors::ERR_MISSING)
);
```

The error is the following:

> Class name must be a valid object or a string

The `AbstractRestEntity` class does not contain any reference to `ErrorConstants`, and when I add the reference there, nothing changes with respect to the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the actual error is missing?

Comment: What do you expect from `$this->errors::ERR_RANGE_VAL`? `$this->errors` is instance of a class, as I can see. What's the point of taking a constant name from instance of a class?

Comment: Sorry I have fixed the code to make it easier to read, the constant was not the issue, the ErrorConstants contains a long list, I just included one as an example. The edited code still throws the same error as before

Comment: Do you __understand__ that constant refers to class, not to class instance?

Comment: @u_mulder, in other instances in my code $this->errors::ERR_MISSING returns the value 'Record could not be found.' which I then send to the frontend to notify the client of what error occurred

Comment: I don't know what happens in other instances, but I suppose `$this->errors` there is not a class instance, it's a string probably.

Comment: It is defined in the same way in other classes and works without issue, but only in this ORM\Entity class does it cause problems

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi I am able to access this constant from other classes using the same approach without issue and it works fine, only in this particular case is it causing me trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u_mulder noted constants refer to class, not to class instance. In order to properly get the constants from your class you could use something like that in your ErrorConstants class:

```
public function getConstants()
{
    $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($this);
    return $reflectionClass->getConstants();
}
```

then in your CwPackagePeriod class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $errorConstants = new ErrorConstants();
    $this->errors = $errorConstants->getConstants();
}
...
throw new InvalidOrMissingParameterException(
   sprintf($this->errors['ERR_MISSING']);
);
```

Of course the simplest solution would be to use just:

```
throw new InvalidOrMissingParameterException(
   sprintf(ErrorConstants::ERR_MISSING);
);
```

Finally I would like to note, although it is not very intuitive, you CAN indeed use `$this->errors::ERR_MISSING` to get a constant. The reason because you get this error is probably because `$this->errors` is not defined in that part of code for some reason.

Comment: Ah yes, I was overthinking it, the simplest solution is the best, thanks!

Comment: I also updated my question to answer your original question.